# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File b'smallsample.csv' does not exist: b'smallsample.csv'

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

In Google Colab, I mounted google drive:

```
from google.colab import drive     #Mounted at gdrive(set directory)
drive.mount("/content/gdrive")
```

and set my path to read the file named `smallsample.csv`:

```
path ='gdrive/My Drive' #/data_analysis/datafiles/reports
df= pd.read_csv('smallsample.csv', sep=',')
```

However, it returned

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File b'smallsample.csv' does not exist: b'smallsample.csv'
```

It doesn't not help if I add `r` to `df= pd.read_csv('smallsample.csv', sep=',')`. I also tried some methods suggested by other posts but none solved this problem. Can someone help please? Cheers.

Comment: Try the absolute path `/content/gdrive/.../smallsample.csv`.

Comment: Hi Michael, it worked. Thank you:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assignin `path = ...` doesn't change the current working directory. Instead, use the absolute path as suggested by Michael, or change the working directory using:

`%cd /content/gdrive/My Drive`

You can observe the current working directory using `%pwd` and the files in the current directory using `%ls`.

Comment: Hi Bob, thanks for your answer. Does `path ='gdrive/My Drive'` do any work here then?

Comment: Nope, the `path = ...` assignment isn't necessary and doesn't have any impact in the snippet you shared.